# psql function written in separate file

Tags: postgresql, psql

i'm learning psql in Postgres. 
My basic question is when i create a function like this one :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION totalRecords ()
RETURNS integer AS $total$
declare
    total integer;
BEGIN
  SELECT count(*) into total FROM COMPANY;
  RETURN total;
END;
$total$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

i must write all of the code in the prompt command line. 
How can i save this code in a script and call it from the command line ? the extentsion of the scirpt must be a .sql ? how can i call this script.

Comment: Type `psql -?` in the console and read output attentively. You will find `-f, --file=FILENAME      execute commands from file, then exit`. As an alternative you can use redirection like `psql < mylovelyscript.sql`. Good luck.

Comment: Full command line is `psql -h hostname -p portnumber -d database -U username -f input.sql -L executionlog.txt -o outputfile.txt`, probably it will be necessary to set `PGPASSWORD` environment variable for session to avoid psql interaction. You can drop any of those parameters if them is default for your purposes.

Comment: oké thanks a lot, but i have a question : what's a PGPASSWORD environment variable ?

Comment: For Windows execute `set PGPASSWORD=<postgrespassword>`, for Linux `export PGPASSWORD=<postgrespassword>` before you call `psql` to avoid that it ask you to enter password for postgres user (it will use <postgrespassword> value instead). [As an alternative](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/libpq-pgpass.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Save your script to a file. Then execute like this:

```
psql -p portnumber -d database -U user -f mysqlscrpt.sql
```

The extension of the script does not matter.

Answer (score 1):

@jkdba's answer is sufficient but, alternatively, if you are already logged in the psql console, you can use:

```
\i <sqlscript>.sql
```

The `\i` being for input. `\o` is output, and it would write to the file instead of bringing it in.
I mention this because this is what made me remember the command :)